# Outputting contents of vector of vectors "vertically" in console

Tags: c++, vector, cout

I have a function in a class that returns results from calculations in the form of a vector of vector of vector of doubles (one set of returns fit neatly into a 2d vector and the other set is separate, so I figured this was the easiest way) that looks like so:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> BackTest::GetResultsSoFar()
{
    std::vector<double> innerVector(3);
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > results(1, innerVector);
    results[0][0] = numberOfExceedances;
    results[0][1] = backTestedDays;
    results[0][2] = numberOfExceedances / (double)backTestedDays;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> detailedResults{ portfolioValueVector, LossVector, VARVector,  exceedancesVector };
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> allResults{results, detailedResults};
    return allResults;
}
```

To output the results in main I simple do:

```
vector<vector<vector<double>>> backTestResults = thisBackTest.GetResultsSoFar();
std::cout << "\n";
std::cout << "\n";
std::cout << "     Backtesting results " << "\n";
std::cout << "\n";
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < backTestResults.size(); i++)
{
    for (unsigned long j = 0; j < backTestResults[i].size(); j++)
    {
        for (unsigned long k = 0; k < backTestResults[i][j].size(); k++)
        {
            std::cout << backTestResults[i][j][k] << " , ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that my four vectors in the second set of results (`detailedResults{ portfolioValueVector, LossVector, VARVector,  exceedancesVector }` above) will all get printed out horizontally in the console making it impossible to get an overview of the values as they all clutter the screen. Is there a simple way I'm not thinking about to output my vectors vertically next to each other in the console?

EDIT: Picture of current output and what I want it like below:
[image]

Comment: Can you give a small example data structure along with the explicit display you want to see for it?

Comment: Hey, sorry could you explain that some more? I'm not sure exactly what you mean

Comment: Give an example `vector<vector<vector<double>>>` (with actual numbers) and show us how you want it displayed (with actual numbers, spaces, commas, and line breaks).

Comment: if `backTestResults = { { {1, 2}, {3, 4} }, { {5, 6}, {7, 8} } }`, how do you want it displayed?

Comment: I also saw that you're stuffing two disparate data sets into a larger vector. Would a `std::tuple<std::vector<std::vector<double>>, std::vector<std::vector<double>>>` make more sense? Or maybe a `struct foo { std::vector<std::vector<double>> biz; std::vector<std::vector<double>> bar; }`?

Comment: Hey, I put an image of what it outputs as currently and what I want it like. I have never used tuple but yes, I can imagine that it would likely be suitable here. But I still have the same issue of outputting my second set of results in the tuple correctly, no?

Comment: Yeah you still need to access it in the same way, but if it helps you keep the objects separate in your head, and leads to shorter coding time, then it's worth it.

Comment: Okay it looks like you really want to return a 1d vector and a 2d vector. Those combined don't equal a 3d vector. You should definitely return at least a `std::tuple<std::vector<double>, std::vector<std::vector<double>>>` or a struct as described above, or use return parameters ("how do I return multiple values from a C++ function?" is a common enough question that you can look up the various techniques). After that it becomes two questions of "how do I output a 1d vector vertically" and "how do I output a 2d vector in column major order?" eat this elephant one bite at a time.

Comment: Another question, for `portfolioValueVector, LossVector, VARVector,  exceedancesVector`, is the `i`th member of any of these vectors more closely related to the other member in its same vector, or more closely related to the `i`th values of the other vectors? If its the latter, than it sounds like you want a `struct DetailedResult { double portfolio_value; double loss; etc... }` and make a vector of those.

Comment: If we have a database of people, is it easier to reason about a `std::vector<Person> people = {{"Smith", "John"}, {"Doe", "Jane"}, ...}` or a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> people = {{"Smith", "Doe", ...}, {"John", "Jane", ...}}`?

Comment: I've put some work into it now and have gotten it to work now by using a tuple as well as reorganizing the creation of my 2d vector so that the ith values were put with each other together in the inner vectors. Thank you for your help and suggestions